# Setting up SLIME via macports

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, macports

I followed the instructions as best I could for installing terminal SLIME on Mac OS X, but when I press M-x it does not prompt me.

I installed emacs and Lisp using the following two sudo commands:

```
sudo port install emacs +carbon
sudo port install sbcl slime
```

I got the following instructions:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/opt/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/slime")
(require 'slime-autoloads)
(setq slime-lisp-implementations
     `((sbcl ("/opt/local/bin/sbcl"))
       (abcl ("/opt/local/bin/abcl"))
       (clisp ("/opt/local/bin/clisp"))))
(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook
           (lambda ()
             (cond ((not (featurep 'slime))
                    (require 'slime) 
                    (normal-mode)))))

(eval-after-load "slime"
   '(slime-setup '(slime-fancy slime-banner)))
```

> Populate the initialization list in SLIME-LISP-IMPLEMENTATIONS with
>   the correct paths to the Common Lisp exectuables you wish to use.

I'm not sure what that last bit means...

Anyways, I've never used Lisp or emacs before, most literal n00b directed instructions would be best. Just the bare minimum to write and execute common lisp with emacs.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're on the right track already. Since you've only installed `sbcl`, and not the other lisps, just cut your initialization code down to this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/opt/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/slime")
(require 'slime-autoloads)
(setq slime-lisp-implementations `((sbcl ("/opt/local/bin/sbcl")))
(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook
  (lambda () (cond ((not (featurep 'slime)) (require 'slime) (normal-mode)))))
(eval-after-load "slime" '(slime-setup '(slime-fancy slime-banner)))
```

After that, use `M-x slime`, and you should be good to go.

Comment: works like a charm! Why didn't I think of that!? Wish I didn't have to use esc for Meta though...

Comment: You shouldn't have to use escape for meta, I have this in my .emacs to use the command key instead: `(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)` There are other options though, see this: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS

Comment: Where do you put that initialization code?  I'm trying to follow along myself and although I know the basics of vim, I am a total emacs novice.  Thanks!